# Android - Timer layout is not getting updated

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am learning to create a simple `stop watch` app. I got layout with three `buttons` and one `textview`. When I click `start` button, it will start the timer.

Single layout and single activity.

```
  public void startTimer(View view){
    running = true;
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    while(running) {
        int hours = seconds / 3600;
        int minutes = (seconds % 60) / 60;
        int sec = seconds % 60;
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        textView.setText(time);
        seconds++;
        if(seconds == 10){
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method called when I click `start` button. I debugged the code. Values are generating properly. But not updating the layout.

Any suggestions?

I get the final result else one by one increase with the following addition

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);
    runTimer(); //I added this extra.
   }
```

Comment: won't you prefer `CountDownTimer` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I do prefer. I wanted to find out the issue in my code. Why layout is not showing the time even when variable gets the right value

Comment: From where are you getting this `seconds`?

Comment: Its a class member. So default value is 0.

Comment: I'm sorry bro for late reply. But why are you calculating these with `0` then.

Comment: The main fact is, It is being updated and working fine, But you are not seeing it because of Rapid execution of the code block. So that you are seeing the final result at first.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna No No No. I see only `00:00:00`. I will update the question to tell more

Comment: I am also trying bro, I've used thread to sleep hold the execution still not working, but I will get on you after making it work

Comment: Finaaaallly, I did it bro, It was really hard to find out the issue but Thread is needed for updating UI. See my **update** section. You can directly copy and paste that. modify a little bit and make variables as field if forced to make final, Hope you'll understand

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an alternate solution on your task,

```
 public void startTimer(View view){
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) { //For 10 seconds

        public void onTick(long seconds) {

            String time = String.format("%02d : %02d ",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(seconds),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(seconds))
            );
            textView.setText(time);
        }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("Finished");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
public void startTimer(View view) {
    running = true;
    seconds = 0;
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int hours = seconds / 3600;
                        int minutes = (seconds % 60) / 60;
                        int sec = seconds % 60;

                         time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
                        textView.setText(time);
                        seconds++;
                    }
                }) ;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(seconds==10){
                running=false;
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: Bro, You are trying hard. Give it a time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Man. I understand that it will work with thread. Will you please tell me the reason behind the thread? plus 1 from my side

Comment: Its maybe because tasks that run on a thread from a thread pool don't have access to UI objects. we need to update UI from `run()` method many times in real time development.

Comment: Bro these codes are still in my PC so, If any issue is left please kindly tell and I will be glad if you accept it if you think there is no issue left.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```
public void startTimer(View view){
    running = true;
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    while(running) {
        int hours = seconds / 3600;
        int minutes = (seconds % 60) / 60;
        int sec = seconds % 60;
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

        seconds++;

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
               textView.setText(time);
             }
        });

        Thread.sleep(1000)

        if(seconds == 10){
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```